# How to test if a Json "contains" another Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, testing, versioning

Let's say I have 2 Jsons:

```
  Json1
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
      "b1": 21,
    }
  }
```

```
  Json2
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
      "b1": 21,
      "b2": 22
    },
    "c": 3
  }
```

Here Json2 "contains" Json1 since for each field we have the same value (including nested fields, such as `b.b1`).
The use-case here is to verify no versioning change.

How would I test for this, besides implementing the logic myself?

Comment: You could take both JSON strings, remove all whitespace, newlines, etc., and then check `json2.Contains(json1)`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride that would result in bad matches even if the structure was different

Comment: This is a rather specific use case. I'd say just implement it yourself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh yea I misunderstood.

Comment: A JSON document is just an array or dictionary of attributes. If you deserialize both strings into a JsonNode, you could use [DeepEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.deepequals) to compare each node from Json2 with the entire Json1 node. That's a pretty brute force approach though.

Comment: @Charlieface This is a different question, he's asking for same-same comparison when I'm asking for "contains". I don't know if the FluentAssert isEquivalent works for this as well, but I'll happily check (if so, I'd accept such as an answer but I do believe it's a different question anyway)

Comment: It's clear what you want for JSON objects, but how should your `Contains()` algorithm treat JSON arrays?  Same array length and contents?

Comment: @dbc I didn't think about it. I think arrays should be checked for ordering as well, but not sure.

Comment: @Charlieface - I really don't see this is as a duplicate.  OP wants to see whether the key/value pairs in one JSON object are a subset of the key/value pairs in another, not whether they are equal.  Should this question be reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Newtonsoft.Json you could do it like that:

```cs
var reference = JObject.Parse("{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}");
var contained = JObject.Parse("{\"b\": 2}");
var notContained = JObject.Parse("{\"b\": 2, \"c\": 3}");

var mergedContained = (JObject)reference.DeepClone();
mergedContained.Merge(contained);
Debug.Assert(JToken.DeepEquals(mergedContained, reference));

var mergedNotContained = (JObject)reference.DeepClone();
mergedNotContained.Merge(notContained);
Debug.Assert(!JToken.DeepEquals(mergedNotContained, reference));
```

But all the cloning and merging looks kinda dumb. I'd rather write a recursive algorithm that traverses a JSON structure and compares it with another on the fly.

Comment: This is fine for `JObject`, but for `JArray` there will be a problem.  The default value for [`JsonMergeSettings.MergeArrayHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonMergeSettings_MergeArrayHandling.htm) looks to be [`MergeArrayHandling.Concat`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm) so, even if the reference and contained are identical, the array concatenation will cause the `DeepEquals()` to fail. Probably `MergeArrayHandling.Merge` (which matches by index) or `MergeArrayHandling.Replace` would be better.

Comment: @dbc would you like to edit the answer to add your suggested improvement? I'm willing to accept this happily